# Convert date and time to elapsed time in decimal hours

Tags: r

I need your help to convert a column of a data.frame containing a date and time to **elapsed time in decimal hours** and save it in another column of the same data.frame. For example I have the following data.frame where each cell is a 1 minute increment from the previous and I would like to get the result shown in the alongside column: Many thanks

```
       df$datetime           df$elapsed (hours) that I want
1993-12-09 14:51:00            0.00             
1993-12-09 14:52:00            0.02             
1993-12-09 14:53:00            0.03             
1993-12-09 14:54:00            0.05             
1993-12-09 14:55:00            0.07             
1993-12-09 14:56:00            0.08             
1993-12-09 14:57:00            0.10             
1993-12-09 14:58:00            0.12             
1993-12-09 14:59:00            0.13             
1993-12-09 15:00:00            0.15             
1993-12-09 15:01:00            0.17             
1993-12-09 15:02:00            0.18             
1993-12-09 15:03:00            0.20             
....     ....                  ....     
1993-12-09 15:24:00            0.55             
1993-12-09 15:25:00            0.57             
1993-12-09 15:26:00            0.58             
1993-12-09 15:27:00            0.60             
1993-12-09 15:28:00            0.62             
1993-12-09 15:29:00            0.63 
...            ....            ....                         
1993-12-09 15:51:01            1.00                             
1993-12-09 15:52:01            1.02             
1993-12-09 15:53:01            1.03             
1993-12-09 15:54:01            1.05             
1993-12-09 15:55:01            1.07             
1993-12-09 15:56:01            1.08 
...      ....                 ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To calculate the difference between two datetimes you can subtract the start from the end. That gives you a time difference which you can convert to a number using `as.numeric` and setting `units` to "hours". I think your start is the datetime in the first row, so using tidyverse you could do something like this...

```r
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  mutate(elapsed = as.numeric(datetime - first(datetime), units = "hours"))
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! I thank you so much!